# Why when trying to running my app in androis studio I'm getting the error: while waiting for device: Could not start AVD ? and how to resolve it?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have windows 10 pro and android phone Galaxy s21 fe 5g

connected the phone with usb to the pc when connecting to the pc it's giving me a message it will be slow charging and the settings are:

[image: settings on the phone]

the software I'm using is android studio flamingo 2022.2.1 patch 1

I followed this tutorial:

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#1

my guess is that my phone is not correctly connected to the pc? but I tried to change the options in the screenshot, but it didn't change much when running the app getting the same error.

Comment: Have you tried enabling developer options and allow USB debugging? Or you won't be able to connect your phone with Android Studio.

Docs on how to enable USB debugging: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options
In Video form: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0usgePpr8_Y